# How to parameterize an array passed to a JComoBox?

Tags: java, swing

I'm doing the following:
`private TestAccount[] accounts;`
`private JComboBox<TestAccount[]> accountComboBox;`

`JComboBox<TestAccount[]>  comboBox = new JComboBox (accounts);`

But get warnings:
The constructor JComboBox(Object[]) belongs to the raw type JComboBox. References to generic type JComboBox() should be parameterized.
The expression of type JComboBox neeads unchecked conversion to conform to JComboBox(TestAccount[]).

How to resolve?

I've tried:
`JComboBox<TestAccount[]>  comboBox = new JComboBox <TestAccount[]>();`
then adding accounts to a default model, but get the same warnings.

Comment: You very probably want a `JComboBox<TestAccount>`, not `<TestAccount[]>`. It gets confused because there is a constructor allowing to pass in an array of the element type.

Comment: `JComboBox<TestAccount>` - You want the generic type `<E>` to be `TestAccount` and use the  public `JComboBox(E[] items)` constructor with an `TestAccount[]` not a `TestAccount[][]` - edit: This is analog to how you would create a `List<String>` and not `List<String[]>`. Even if the data Structure in the end can hold more than one of your generic type the generic type itself does not need to be an array.